# How Aurelia Webpack plugin is working?

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I've spent recently several hours on Webpack + various frameworks (like Vue) in order to test them a little bit.

Then I've started to work on Aurelia + Webpack, but after hours of search and config tweaking, I can't understand what's going on.

Here's my understanding about webpack :

- It grabs one or several entry files, in the `entry` object
- It creates one or several bundles, configured in the `output` object
- all files imported / required in the entry files are being processed by Webpack
- Webpack uses loaders in order to apply transformation to files. For example, loader babel with preset `es2015` for .js files, Vue loader for .vue files, etc...
- You can configure plugins that will do additional processing on top of all of this. For example, `HMTLWebpackPlugin` will take an HTML template and automatically insert the correct `<script>` tags corresponding to the bundle you want to generate.

Fine.

So for Aurelia, I've installed `aurelia-webpack-plugin` + `aurelia-loader` + `aurelia-loader-webpack`. But how this is supposed to work in Webpack ?

What I've more or less understood is :

- when webpack is launched, the AureliaPlugin kicks in and read everything in the `src` folder (by default)
- from there, I think it's supposed to grab the `aurelia-app` defined in the `index.html` and the configuration in the main JS file, then pull all the components defined there.

But it's not working like that, at least, not in my configuration. What I've discovered is that I have to feed `aurelia-framework` + `aurelia-loader` + `aurelia-loader-webpack` as one of Webpack's entries in order to have all my components / apps discovered and processed correctly. If I only feed the main Aurelia JS files (containing Aurelia configuration), Webpack process the file and stops there.

Loading the Aurelia modules in a Webpack entry is something done a lot, for example in the [`skeleton` projects](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-typescript-webpack/webpack.config.ts#L77)

So, is it something needed ? I have to import / bundle the `aurelia-loader` and `aurelia-loader-webpack` in order to have the proper processing of all my Aurelia apps / components ?

If this is something that has to be done in order to correctly process Aurelia, why this is not something done automatically by the plugin ?

I'm not judging, I'm just trying to understand what's done by Webpack when dealing with Aurelia app.

For reference, here's my Webpack configuration :

```
var path = require('path');
var AureliaWebpackPlugin = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const coreBundles = {
  // these will be included in the 'aurelia' bundle (except for the above bootstrap packages)
  aurelia: [
    'aurelia-framework',
      'aurelia-loader',
      'aurelia-loader-webpack'
  ]
}

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/main'
    },
    output: {
        path: "./dist",
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new AureliaWebpackPlugin({
        }),
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: "src/index.html"
        })
        ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css"},
            {test: /\.html$/, loader: "html"},
            {test: /\.(png|svg|eot|ttf|woff\d*)$/, loader: "file"}
        ]
    }
};
```

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/bigopon/framework/blob/e44fcbd1cfe62a65a4331ae4b7b63e0c833c347e/doc/article/en-US/setup-webpack.md#using-normal-webpack-configuration

Answer (score 0):

It is discussed with a lot of details on the wiki pages of the repo for the plugin

https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/wiki